# What will be more computationally intensive n if conditions or loop till n with one if condition?

Tags: loops, if-statement

We can even compare it with switch,
n time if conditions or switch case with n cases

Comment: switch............

Comment: @Yvain
why? what do you think could be the reason? 
greater is more efficient.
switch(n) > n if conditions
what about loop?

Comment: First of all, a loop with one if will not produce as much assembly code as a series of instruction, that is what loops are for, When over it tests the loop counter and jumps back to the beginning if not yet done. Also I'm not following you when you are talking about a switch without a case. Switches are nothing without their case statements.
So i'm answering the title or your question and ignoring the rest.
Normaly, you use either several if statements or a switch, to avoid too much redondancy, and having an if in a loop will work only if you are making a boolean test.